# Should Ganesh idol not be taken on Tuesday after the Ganesh festival and put it in water in a temple?

Tags: ganesha

Ganesh chaturthi festival happened on 2nd September and it is considered that at 9th day one should take his idol and put in water in a temple. 9th day being Tuesday today, can we do this process? Some are saying in Tuesday we should not do. What our hindu scriptures say on this?

Comment: "one should take his idol and put in water in a temple" What do you mean by this? Idols are immersed in lakes. Why temple?